# Autohotkey not working in alttab

Tags: autohotkey

```
ShiftAltTab::AltTab
```

what i am trying to do is change ShiftAltTab to Alt tab only but my code does not work and it give me an error ("invalid hotkey")

Comment: Opps! my bad this is the correct way to do it Alt  & Tab::ShiftAltTab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

!Tab::

Send, {Shift Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}

KeyWait, Alt

Send, {Shift Up}{Alt Up}

return